# Why is self.splitViewController suddenly nil in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iOS Universal app that uses a standard `UISplitViewController`.

Almost since I started working on the app I had the following code in place to link the master view controller on the left with the detail view controller on the right:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.detailViewController = (CustomViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}
```

After some recent changes the last line stopped working and thus broke some functionality. The reason for this behavior is that `self.splitViewController` is `nil` at this point. Moving the last line to `viewWillAppear:` fixes the problem, but IMHO this isn't the completely right spot.

The changes I made aren't really related to this, I didn't made changes to the controller hierarchy or the storyboard I use. So I can't explain where this behavior originates from. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a dynamic accessor for your splitViewController instance so it will never return nil, or of course check if nil in viewDidLoad.

e.g.

```
- (CustomViewController *)splitViewController 
{
    if (splitViewController == nil) {
      splitViewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] init]; 
    }
    return splitViewController; 
}
```

Comment: Checking for `nil` in `viewDidLoad` doesn't help, as well as initializing the controller manually, this isn't something I should need to care about when using a storyboard. I could just call `[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController]` in the getter, though.